# Объясните, пожалуйста, суть ключевого слова fast pattern в IDS/IPS Suricata?

Tags: linux, rules

Официальную документацию и wiki я прочел.
Посмотрел примеры правил с использованием этой сущности.
Все равно четкого понимания не появилось.

Comment: но вы ведь сделали какие-то выводы после прочтения? можно для начала их здесь опубликовать, и дальше если что это поможет отвечающим от ваших знаний отталкиваться

Comment: Как я понял, это ключевое слово, которое меняет приоритет обработки содержимого правила. То есть критерий, указанный перед fast pattern, становится первоочередным. Это нужно из-за того что по умолчанию суриката в первую очередь обрабатывает более сложные и "наполненные" критерии. Так?